# Knockout.js click not firing inside of jQuery Steps Plugin

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-steps

I am using the [jQuery Steps plugin](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) to create a wizard and on step two, you will add 1..* fields, which is an array of JSON objects that'll get posted to the server. I'm trying to use Knockout to show an input for each field name.

On click, a new empty field should get pushed to the array and a textbox should display. However, the addField function doesn't fire when inside the form/jquery steps. If I take it out, it does. Is there a way to prevent jQuery steps from interfering with the binding? Here's a condensed version of the code:

```js
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.fields = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.addField = function() {
        // push field to self.fields
    }

}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

// jQuery Steps
var form = $("#stepsForm");

form.children("div").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    stepsOrientation: "vertical"
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-steps/1.1.0/jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
 
<form id="stepsForm" action="#" novalidate>
    <div class="form-container">
        <h3>Section1</h3>
        <section>
            <table class="table table-condensed">

                <tr data-bind="foreach: fields">
                    <td>
                        <div data-bind="text:FieldName"></div>test
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <button data-bind="click: addField">Add another</button>

        </section>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you use a "steps" custom binding handler? (Rhetorical question, I don't  see you using one, but I think you should.)

Comment: No I don't. This is really my first crack and Knockout. Some other searches I did eluded to using a Custom Binding handler but after reading through the KO documentation on it I couldn't wrap my ahead around it enough to know if it was applicable to my situation

Comment: I don't know jQuery-steps, but I know my way around Knockout pretty well. Usually you don't want to have a knockout app with a second library that does UI manipulation without a proper binding handler that connects it to knockout.

Comment: That said, after turning your code above into a runnable snippet, it seems to work - at least it adds something, I'm not sure if that's what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Indeed, your edits work. It makes me wonder if it's perhaps the order in which the libraries are referenced. I'll poke around and report back. Thanks

Comment: jQuery-steps is not *used* in any way in the code above, so for the moment this is a run-off-the-mill Knockout app that adds table cells. You will need to detail how you plan to use the steps plugin, exactly.

Comment: Bah. Duh. Back to the drawing board. I'll include the Steps code above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105582/discussion-between-elliott-and-tomalak).

Answer (score 0):

This issue came down to the timing of JavaScript execution. It was complicated by the fact that I'm using server data to load Knockout objects (without ajax). This is where I finally netted:

My JavaScript loads in this order:

1. jQuery, jQuery steps, Knockout, etc (bundled)
2. JavaScript file for the view
3. Inline JavaScript embedded in the view

**#2 - JavaScript file for the view (e.g. fields.js)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var form = $('#stepsForm');

    form.children("div").steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        stepsOrientation: "vertical"
    });
});
```

**#3 - Embedded JavaScript in the view (e.g. fields.html)**

```
<script>
    function AppViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.fields = ko.observableArray([]); 
        self.addField = function () {
            // push field to self.fields
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Used MVC Razor engine to load some other server data into other KO objects here. (omitted for clarity)
        ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

    })

</script>
```